# firebase phone authentication ios does not return anything

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
    func loginwithOTP(phNumber: String, completion: @escaping OTPCompletionHandler) {
            
            PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phNumber, uiDelegate: nil) { verificationID, error in
                
                print("otplogin", verificationID)
                print("otplogin", error)
                                        
                completion(verificationID, error)
            }
        }
    
func verifyOTP(verificationID: String, verificationCode: String, completion: @escaping AuthCompletionHandler) {
            
            let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: verificationID, verificationCode: verificationCode)
            
            auth.signIn(with: credential) { authResult, error in
                            
                completion(authResult, error)
            }
        }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6EIP.png

I've added the following permissions as well as a url scheme in case the silent notification fails but the problem is that the function doesn't even run nor is it even printing any of the print statements inside it. My Firebase SDK verion is 10.8.0 and I am deploying to iOS 16.

I even created a new project entirely just to see if something was wrong with this one but to no avail